# Using ProcessPoolExecutor for Web Scraping: How to get data back to queue and results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I have written a program to crawl a single website and scrape certain data. I would like to speed up its execution by using `ProcessingPoolExecutor`. However, I am having trouble understanding how I can convert from single threaded to concurrent.

Specifically, **when creating a job (via `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()`), can I pass a class/object and args instead of a function and args?**

And, if so, **how do return data from those jobs to the queue for tracking visited pages AND a structure for holding scraped content?**

I have been using [this](https://edmundmartin.com/multi-threaded-crawler-in-python/) as a jumping off point, as well as reviewing the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html) and [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) docs (with, frankly, the latter going a bit over my head). I've also Googled/Youtubed/SO'ed around quite a bit to no avail.

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


class Scraper:
    """
    Scrapes a single url
    """

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url # url of page to scrape
        self.internal_urls = None
        self.content = None
        self.scrape()

    def scrape(self):
        """
        Method(s) to request a page, scrape links from that page
        to other pages, and finally scrape actual content from the current page
        """
        # assume that code in this method would yield urls linked in current page
        self.internal_urls = set(scraped_urls)

        # and that code in this method would scrape a bit of actual content
        self.content = {'content1': content1, 'content2': content2, 'etc': etc}


class CrawlManager:
    """
    Manages a multiprocess crawl and scrape of a single site
    """

    def __init__(self, seed_url):
        self.seed_url = seed_url
        self.pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
        self.processed_urls = set([])
        self.queued_urls = Queue()
        self.queued_urls.put(self.seed_url)
        self.data = {}

    def crawl(self):
        while True:
            try:
                # get a url from the queue
                target_url = self.queued_urls.get(timeout=60)

                # check that the url hasn't already been processed
                if target_url not in self.processed_urls:
                    # add url to the processed list
                    self.processed_urls.add(target_url)
                    print(f'Processing url {target_url}')

                    # passing an object to the
                    # ProcessPoolExecutor... can this be done?
                    job = self.pool.submit(Scraper, target_url)

                    """
                    How do I 1) return the data from each 
                    Scraper instance into self.data?
                    and 2) put scraped links to self.queued_urls?
                    """

            except Empty:
                print("All done.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawler = CrawlManager('www.mywebsite.com')
    crawler.crawl()
```

Comment: An HTTP request/response is a network-IO dominated cycle.  You may want to consider using threading or async io rather than multiprocessing.

Comment: @BradSolomon, thanks! The <a href="https://edmundmartin.com/multi-threaded-crawler-in-python/">article<a> which inspired me actually used ThreadPoolExecutor, but I read a different article which advocated for the use of processes over threads for parallelization. Obviously, I missed the contextual requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this page, I was able figure this out for myself.

Per @brad-solomon's advice, I switched from `ProcessPoolExecutor` to `ThreadPoolExecutor` to manage the concurrent aspects of this script (see his comment for further details).

W.r.t. the original question, the key was to utilize the `add_done_callback` method of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in conjunction with a modification to `Scraper.scrape` and a new method `CrawlManager.proc_scraper_results` as in the following:

```python
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class Scraper:
    """
    Scrapes a single url
    """

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url # url of page to scrape
        self.internal_urls = None
        self.content = None
        self.scrape()

    def scrape(self):
        """
        Method(s) to request a page, scrape links from that page
        to other pages, and finally scrape actual content from the current page
        """
        # assume that code in this method would yield urls linked in current page
        self.internal_urls = set(scraped_urls)

        # and that code in this method would scrape a bit of actual content
        self.content = {'content1': content1, 'content2': content2, 'etc': etc}

        # these three items will be passed to the callback
        # function with in a future object
        return self.internal_urls, self.url, self.content


class CrawlManager:
    """
    Manages a multiprocess crawl and scrape of a single website
    """

    def __init__(self, seed_url):
        self.seed_url = seed_url
        self.pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
        self.processed_urls = set([])
        self.queued_urls = Queue()
        self.queued_urls.put(self.seed_url)
        self.data = {}


    def proc_scraper_results(self, future):
        # get the items of interest from the future object
        internal_urls, url, content = future._result[0], future._result[1], future._result[2]

        # assign scraped data/content
        self.data[url] = content

        # also add scraped links to queue if they
        # aren't already queued or already processed
        for link_url in internal_urls:
            if link_url not in self.to_crawl.queue and link_url not in self.processed_urls:
                self.to_crawl.put(link_url)


    def crawl(self):
        while True:
            try:
                # get a url from the queue
                target_url = self.queued_urls.get(timeout=60)

                # check that the url hasn't already been processed
                if target_url not in self.processed_urls:
                    # add url to the processed list
                    self.processed_urls.add(target_url)
                    print(f'Processing url {target_url}')

                    # add a job to the ThreadPoolExecutor (note, unlike original question, we pass a method, not an object)
                    job = self.pool.submit(Scraper(target_url).scrape)

                    # to add_done_callback we send another function, this one from CrawlManager
                    # when this function is itself called, it will be pass a `future` object
                    job.add_done_callback(self.proc_scraper_results)

            except Empty:
                print("All done.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawler = CrawlManager('www.mywebsite.com')
    crawler.crawl()
```

The result of this is a very significant reduction in duration of this program.